# How to diagnose reason for infinite loop in Svelte reaction

Tags: svelte

I'm having issues with infinite reaction loops in Svelte. No matter how much I try stepping through it line by line, I cannot find a circular dependency that would be causing it. Svelte's internal code is itself too obtuse to understand. The call stack displayed in DevTools does not show a long stack, it might be replacing repeated call stack entries rather than appending them, so I cannot tell from that what the true execution path is.

What debugging strategy could I employ to understand what's causing an infinite loop when one occurs?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend familiarizing yourself with the compiled component code.

- Components have a `$$self.$$.update` function, which is what gets executed if the component is marked as dirty due to some invalidation. Reactive statement will be compiled into this. If this function e.g. contains asynchronous code that invalidates the component it can easily cause a loop.
- Look at `$$invalidate` invocations, those mark a component as dirty and set which part of its state has been changed. Event handlers, reactive statements and any other code that changes state will result in such calls.

One common issue is that reactive blocks contain too many references to state variables and due to how Svelte currently evaluates those blocks, invalidating everything being used, this can cause statements to be run unexpectedly.

The dirty state gets cleared after the update, which is why infinite loops should usually not happen. However, if there is any asynchronous code in the update, which thus will be executed after the flag has been cleared, you can run into issues.

Comment: I have 2,209 $$invalidate locations. All of them (but one, presumably) is expected reaction. How do I find the one that is unexpected? I keep stepping through them but there are so many it doesn't make sense to me. Stepping through over two thousand of them would take half a day, and if I I don't know what I'm looking for, the chances are I'll step right past the one causing the issue. Is there a way to log every $$invalidate call?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a DevTools option for listing every async call as it happens?

Comment: Would recommend trying to isolate the issue more first. Remove components, reactive statements, event handlers etc. until the issue disappears.